# Returning value from screen/route/navigator in React Native?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

Is it possible to return a value from a Screen/Route/Navigator like this? Or how is it possible to work around this?

```
let result = this.props.navigation.navigate('NewScreen', {item: this.state.item});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `navigate`, you're allowed a second parameter, which is used exactly how you have it here.

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('NewScreen', {item: this.state.item})
```

So if you navigate from say, **CurrentScreen**, to **NewScreen**, while passing in `{item: this.state.item}`, you can then retrieve that value in **NewScreen** by calling `this.props.navigation.getParam('item', /*some default value here*/)`. You can read more about that [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/params.html)

Comment: Yeah ...but it's more if I make changes in NewScreen and want to pass them back to CurrentScreen.

Comment: If you want to share data between screens, it's advisable for you to use Redux to keep an overarching store above all your components.

Comment: Ah well ...just calling CurrentScreen with parameters instead of GoBack() ....but have to switch to Redux too :-)